# WordPress header location redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

having a problem here with WordPress. I want to redirect the page to a specific .php file inside a folder (php/adminpage.php) whenever `$_SESSION` variable is equals to 1. Let's say the session variable is 1:

```
<?php
 if ((isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] == '1')) {
 header ("Location: php/adminpage.php");
?>
```

But the browser returns "Not Found". Any ways to get it to work?

UPDATE [SOLVED]: Using the full path works. Thanks to @andrewsi. Working code:

```
<?php session_start();  
if ((isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {
header ("Location: wp-content/themes/euro/php/adminpage.php");
}
```

?>

Comment: seems that php/adminpage.php simply doesn't exist. Is the path really correct?

Comment: is the page with this code in the root of the website?

Comment: yes it does exist, it's located here: "**C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\euro\php**"

Comment: Are you deing redirected to the right place, r.g. should the redirect be /somedir/php/adminpage.php?

Comment: Is this before any HTML has been outputted?

Comment: this code is on the very top of index.php, which is a custom theme. index.php is located here obviously: "**C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\euro**"

Comment: @user3125817 - try using the full path : `/wp-content/themes/euro/php/adminpage.php`. WordPress does some very odd things with includes.

Comment: Try using `echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0.1;url=URLHERE'>";`. Works for me sometimes when header doesn't.

Comment: update: solved! @andrewsi pls post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a relative path:

```
 header ("Location: php/adminpage.php");
```

That will look for a folder below where the current file is, and look for `adminpage.php` in there.

But WordPress does some funny things with page names and .htaccess, so your current page might not be where you expect it to be; it's generally always better to use a full path, which is a lot less ambiguous:

header("Location: /wp-content/themes/euro/php/adminpage.php");

And don't forget to `exit` after calling it, too, so code execution stops on the page from which you are redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an actual URL location?

```
header ("Location: php/adminpage.php");
```

To my eyes it seems like a file system path.  Because is your local setup at this URL:

```
localhost
```

And then this would be the location of that file?

```
localhost/php/adminpage.php
```

Also, I would clean up your code like so:

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('login', $_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['login']) && intval($_SESSION['login']) == 1)) {
  header("Location: php/adminpage.php");
  }
?>
```

By using `array_key_exists` you prevent unset index errors & by using `intval` you are assured there  is a numerical value in place.

Comment: Location of the file is `C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\euro\php` and the file he is placing the code in is located at `C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\euro`. Refer to comments in the orig post