# WordPress redirect if user isn't logged in

Tags: wordpress

I have created custom registration/login pages in my WordPress project and when a user logs in I store them in the session. I want to give permission to view my website posts and pages only to those users who are signed in. I have written this code to check if session has user and redirect to login page if no in my `functions.php` file, but it doesn't work. Here is my code at the beginning of `functions.php`:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

    header('Location: /wordpress_grig/login');

}
```

I have also tried to do `wp_redirect('wordpress_grig/login');` and `auth_redirect();` but none work. 
Can someone please tell me how can this be done. 
Thank you.

Comment: make this as a permanent redirect `Eg: header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: /wordpress_grig/login");
exit();`

Comment: I get a message of `The page is not available
Localhost has redirected too many times.`

Answer (score 1):

We will use the init action provided by WordPress to handle starting a PHP session. First, we add the action that will call a function called start_session like this when WordPress first initiates.(Add following in functions.php)

```
add_action('init', 'start_session', 1);
```

Remove session_start();

Use following code to check session is set or not, redirect user accordingly : Ref: [WordPress header location redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722547/wordpress-header-location-redirect)

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

    header('Location: /wordpress_grig/login');

}
```

Comment: When I remove `session_start()` and add `add_action('init', 'start_session', 1);` it gives me a warning saying:

 `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'start_session' not found or invalid function name in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress_grig\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 286`.

Comment: Did you add it in functions.php?.

Comment: Yes I added the code in the beginning of functions.php file

Comment: Add it in last. it will check.

Comment: dont use session_start() anywhere. It should work. Remove add_action('init', 'start_session', 1); from functions.php. now check is error coming?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196707/discussion-between-pawan-thakur-and-grigory-volkov).